# how can i get alert when i get 2 different item in the oracle query while fetching the data?

Tags: database, oracle

I want alert when i am fetching two different item in the oracle query
basically i want to check what ever i am searching it should from one policy when every i any getting two different policy i should get alert or some remark in another query that more then one item got fetch
for example

when i am fetching the data from oracle using the query i want the single item in the column and if i get multiple item i should get the alert

select * from table policy_id in  ('100')

[image]

Comment: sir still the result what i want i didnt found the query i am running SELECT CC.POLICY_ID, CC.CLAIM_ID, case_id, decode (count (), 1, null, 'multiple polie FROM CLAIM CC where policy_id in ('1234') group by CC.POLICY_ID, CC.CLAIM_ID, case_id; 


i am not getting any alert even though i have different claim 
in the last column i am getting null value 
can you check and help please

Answer (score 0):

By asking, "when do I get 2 different items", or "when I have two distinct values" for a given key, you must aggregate rows in order to compute an aggregate value. COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, STDDEV, etc... are all aggregate functions that operate on multiple rows. But for them to operate on multiple rows, you must raise the granularity of your data to a higher level, or what we call "group by". Group by the key column(s) and aggregate across your fact columns to summarize those facts within those groups.

In your case, group by the columns for which you want to see unique values in separate rows. Then count how many rows were included in each group by using the COUNT(*) function. You may then wrap the output of that in a CASE or DECODE to conditionally test that output and return something different based on that output. In my example, test for 1, otherwise if more than one, you have multiple rows sharing the same key values. DECODE arguments are (test value, comparison value, result-if-true, result-if-false). So below will show "multiple policies" if there are 2 or more rows with the same policy,claim, req values, and NULL/empty if there are not.

```
SELECT policy,claim,req,DECODE(COUNT(*),1,NULL,'multiple policies') alert
  FROM table
 WHERE policyid = 100
 GROUP BY policy,claim,req
```

Comment: how to do in this
i have edited the query

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post

Comment: is that better?

Comment: sir still the result what i want i didnt found

the query i am running 
SELECT CC.POLICY_ID, CC.CLAIM_ID, case_id, decode (count (*), 1, null, 'multiple polie FROM CLAIM CC where policy_id in ('1234') group by CC.POLICY_ID, CC.CLAIM_ID, case_id;
POLICY_ID CLAIM_ID CASE_ID DECODE (COUNT(*),1,NULL, MULTIPLEPO...Y
123   628   134829 
123   585   132587 
123   829   134823 

i am not getting any alert even though i have different claim 
in the last column i am getting null value 
can you check and help please

Comment: check the key columns. do you want alert only if there are mutiple rows with the same policy,claim and req? Or just the same policy & claim? Or just the same policy? Whatever you need, adjust the GROUP BY and select clauses to the grouping that meets your need